# imshow() function in opencv gives a window with not responding message

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Whenever I use the imshow() function in opencv in it generates a window with the message 'Not responding'. I have tried uninstalling and installing the opencv package but it still does not work.
Whenever I try running this

```
img = cv2.imread('hand.png')
cv2.imshow('Hand',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It opens a window with title and Not responding message
I'am using Python 3.9
and OpenCV-python 4.5

Comment: Does it work if you remove the destroyAllWindows? Can you try to call cv2.namedWindow('Hand') once before the imshow? Typically this shouldnt be necessary, but please try.

Comment: the `waitKey` **should** have taken care of the GUI event processing, so this **should not** have caused an unresponsive window... what else can you tell us? as it stands, I can't reproduce the issue (I can reproduce that it displays an image properly) given that code. show us the console output of your program.

Comment: After writing the code again in a new project file it is suddenly working